Limit lit property to predefined strings
I am defining a custom text input component in lit (ie: <custom-textinput>)
I want a custom property called type which is "text" by default but the developer can pass in text | number | email | tel which are all valid inputs on the standard html <input>
This is my current code:
@customElement("custom-textinput")
export class CustomTextInput extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: String }) type: "text" | "number" | "email" | "tel" = "text";

  render() {
    return html`
    <input type = ${this.type}/>
   `
  }

Other types should be restricted (ie: radio button checkbox) because I am creating different components for them. However right now, when I use <custom-textinput> and for testing purposes do <custom-textinput type="radio"> it renders the radiobutton input instead of defaulting to type="text because I did not include "radio" as an option in my type property. How can I restrict this to only allow my predetermined types and not anything that is valid on the standard html <input> element?

I don't think Lit can do that right now, but you could add a runtime check and log a warning to the console.

Sound like enums : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enums-in-javascript/

You can create a custom accessor to only allow certain values.
const VALID_TYPE = new Set(['text', 'number', 'email', 'tel']);

@customElement("custom-textinput")
export class CustomTextInput extends LitElement {
  #type: "text" | "number" | "email" | "tel" = "text";

  @property()
  set type(val: string) {
    if (VALID_TYPE.has(val)) {
      this.#type = val;
    } else {
      console.warn(`Tried to set invalid type: "${val}". Defaulting to "text".`);
      this.#type = "text";
    }
  }

  get type() {
    return this.#type;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
    <input type = ${this.type}/>
   `
  }

